# Using link_to to trigger an increment action in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been butting my head against a wall trying to figure this sucker out.

Basically, I have a 'Quote' model that has 3 fields - content, author and votecount.

Votecount is an integer, and I want to be able to add a vote (increment) from the quotes/index view using a link. This is what I've come up with so far:

views/quotes/index.html.erb

```
<% @quotes.each do |quote| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= quote.content %></td>
    <td><%= quote.author %></td>
    <td><%= quote.votecount %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', quote %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_quote_path(quote) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Upvote', quote_upvote_path(quote) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', quote, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

quotes_controller.rb

```
  def upvote
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    @quote.increment!(:votecount)
    redirect_to quotes_path
  end
```

Routes.rb

```
  resources :quotes do
    get 'upvote'
  end
```

And this is the error message I receive:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in QuotesController#upvote
Couldn't find Quote with 'id'=
```

So the action isn't able to find the quote ID, however it's in the actual URL so I'm not sure what I'm bollocksing up here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the upvote action as a member action:

```
resources :quotes do
  get 'upvote', on: :member
end
```

See the [Rails routing documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) for more information.

Comment: You are a legend. Thanks so much!
I had to change:
<%= link_to 'Upvote', quote_upvote_path(quote) %>
to
<%= link_to 'Upvote', upvote_quote_path(quote) %>
But then it worked like a charm :)

Comment: just a reminder.. You should use POST instead of GET request, because you are updating resource...